# Deep linking with React Navigation for protected screens

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, deep-linking

I am building an app with Expo Managed Workflow leveraging React Navigation, EAS Build etc.

React Navigation has a `linking` config that can be used to wire up screens to deep link paths.  The issue I am facing is that the deep links are working when the user has the app opened already but not when the deep link opens the app from a closed state.

My best guess is this is because the deep link is trying to navigate before my authentication logic exposes the "Protected screens". e.g.

```
!isAuth ? <LogIn /> : <ProtectedScreens />
```

I can't seem to find any good documentation or examples on the best way to handle this and detect a deep link but wait until React Navigation has rendered the `<ProtectedScreens />`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Was recently trying to figure this out myself and the documentation from react-navigation is really poor on this regard.

The problem is that you are probably rendering a single `<NavigationContainer>` regardless of whether the user is authenticated or not and changing the context of the navigation container based on the auth status. A way to get around that is by having two `<NavigationContainer>`. i.e. :

```
...
const isAuth = useAuth();

return isAuth ? (
  <NavigationContainer key={1}>
    <LogIn />
  </NavigationContainer>
) : (
  <NavigationContainer key={2} linking={yourLinkingConfig}>
    <ProtectedScreens />
  </NavigationContainer>
);

...
```

I can confirm the above works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by buying into the new paradigm from Expo and leveraging Expo Router.  Now also Expo Router V2.

This abstracts away a bit from boiler plate needed from React Navigation but definitely simplifies handling scenarios.

Overall, you can create a custom hook that manages the Expo Router state and goes to different parts of yours apps by leveraging `useSegments` hook from Expo.

Something like

```
type AuthContext = {
  user: User | null;
};

type AuthProviderProps = { children: React.ReactNode; user: User | null };

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContext | null>(null);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children, user }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  useProtectedRoute(user);
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

function useProtectedRoute(user: User | null) {
  const segments = useSegments();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const inAuthGroup = segments[0] === '(auth)';
    const isSignedIn = segments[0] === '(main)';

    if(!user && isSignedIn) {
      return router.replace('/phoneAuth');
    } else if (inAuthGroup && user) {
      return router.replace('/tabs');
    } 
  }, [user?.id, segments]);
}
```